# Whats the execution order in node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

So the problem is im cant wrap my head around in node.js code execution, here is the code im using atm

```
app.get('/cetvrti',(req,res,next)=>{
data=[];
for(i=0;i<12;i++){

    let Qf=db.query("SELECT Broj FROM tblPolisa WHERE ZastupnikID='"+IdZastupnik+"' AND DatumIzdavanja BETWEEN '"+datum[i].str+"' AND '"+datum[i].end+"';",(err,result,field)=>{
        
        console.log(result+'result prvi');
        if(err)throw err;
        else{
            console.log('pocetak else loopa');
            if(result.length<1)data.push(0);
            else data.push(result.length);
            
            console.log(data);

            
        

        }
    })
}
function rendering(d){
    console.log('ovo je console.log prije renderinga'+d);
    res.render('cetvrti-final',{zastupnik:d});
}
rendering(data);
```

})

(the `datum[i].str` and `datum[i].end` is just some array i use to filter trough like months in a year so yeah)
and the like problematic part for me here is that the `console.log('ovo je console.log prije renderinga'+d);` is executing before the for loop and all the console.logs there, so by my thinking its rendering as well before its going throughout the loop, and thats why i have no data displayed in zastupnik/on page when it loads, it still executes it is just that i think it like first rendering without data then getting the data which is pointless cuz i already rendered my page... Any advice or tips...as i said im new, i dont know how all these shenanigans work :D .

Comment: Is `db.query` asynchronous? - edit: I just saw the callback

Comment: Have a read of the duplicate question. You can't modify `data` like this.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what do you mean? what are you suggesting?

Comment: Once inside a callback, all following code which uses that data must be inside that callback. Promises help because it stops "callback nesting hell". Async/await allows the code to look synchronous.

Comment: @evolutionxbox well my res.render is inside the app.get callback, do you mean i need to put it in db.query callback? i mean it would just render 12 times if im not mistaken and for data i have it as a global variable so i think i can use it in res.render

Comment: Currently, yes.